# I don't know why my image is not showing on the frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, label

So, I do not know why my image is not showing because I put the image in the right folder and I believe that the code below is right. The result of this code is just a blank white frame background. I thought the image was corrupted but I tried a different image and its the same result. Anyway I will be highly grateful if anyone could solve this.

```
package fia_project;
import java.awt.Color;
java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;



     public class Fia_test extends JFrame {
     public Frame kenny;

    public Fia_test(){
    super("");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(350, 100); 
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE); 

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("speaker.png");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon);
    add(label2);
       }


    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Fia_test t = new Fia_test();


  }
  }
```

Comment: *"I put the image in the right folder"* - And what folder would that be?

Comment: I put the image in the src folder and in the build folder. Same result

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: This has been asked so many times before.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This gets asked to often

Comment: Sorry guys i'm kind of new to this.

Comment: NetBeans IDE @MadProgrammer

Comment: Then you shouldn't have a problem, Netbeans bundles pretty much everything in the `src` directory, excluding `*.java` files, into the result Jar file

Comment: @ReubenUkah: Hopefully this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), will also be able to add something to your knowledge :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ImageIO.read` instead of `ImageIcon` as it will generate an error if the image can not be loaded, much more useful for diagnostics.  See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

`ImageIcon(String)` expects that the specified `String` represents a file on the file system.  From the looks of you code, it is possible that you've placed the image within the source directory of your code.

Assuming that the image has been bundled into the resulting Jar file, you will no longer be able to access the image as if it was a file on the file system, but will need to use `Class#getResource` to load it...

For example...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("speaker.png"));
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
```

Assuming that `speaker.png` is in the same directory as the class file.